# Can I align two divs horizontally using CSS properties only inside the pseudo elements associated with the divs?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have two divs. I want to align them horizontally using `::before` and/or `::after`. The float, display, etc. should only be applied to the pseudo elements and not the two divs they are associated with. 
`o1` and `o2` are the class attribute values of the two divs.

```css
.o1 {
      border: 10px solid red;
      border-radius: 50px;
      width:30px;
      height:30px;
    }

    .o1::after {    } 

    .o2 {
      border: 10px solid orange;
      border-radius: 50px;
      width:30px;
      height:30px;
    }

    .o2::before {    }
```

```html
<div class="o1"></div><!--
    --><div class="o2"></div>
```

Comment: I'm unsure what it is you are trying to do. WHY can't we apply properties to the divs classes?

Comment: Hi, wait, you would like to align/float this two divs above without float? Than you can use flexbox?

Answer (score 0):

## NO

I think you are confusing the idea that a **single** element can be vertically centered in a **parent** by using a pseudo-element on the **parent**.

```css
* {-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;}

.o1 {
  border: 10px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.parent {
  height: 90px;
  background: pink;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.parent::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="o1"></div>
</div>
```

However, as you will note, this requires not only a parent but **also** additional properties on the target element,, namely:

```
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
```

There is **NO** property that can be applied to pseudo-elements of block level sibling divs that would vertically align those divs to each other.

You need to apply additional styling to the elements themselves..or their **parent element**, in which case there are various options for vertical alignment of child elements.

```css
.o1 {
  border: 10px solid red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
}

.o2 {
  border: 10px solid orange;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
}

[class^="o"] {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="o1"></div><!--
--><div class="o2"></div>
```